# Can the Tooling API be used to determine which Apex class the current Apex class extends from?

Tags: apex, api, tooling-api, winter14

Does anyone know of a way to use the Tooling API to determine which Apex class the current class extends from?  I have looked at the SymbolTable but cannot see any indication that this information is revealed.

Thanks for the help.

Cheers!

Comment: Do you need to use the Tooling API? You can do this with pure Apex. Let me know and i'll post an answer that is pure Apex.

Comment: @zachelrath - If you would not mind sharing the code, I would appreciate it.

Comment: John, if the answer given answers your question, please vote it up and mark it as accepted --- thanks!

Comment: @zachelrath - your answer is a fine alternative.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that the Tooling API does not support this information ...at least not in v29.0

Answer (score 1):

Here are some pure-Apex solutions for determining whether a given Apex Class extends another given Apex Class.

**(Option 1) 
Query the ApexClass object for its Body field, and parse out the body as a string to find the class that it extends**

```
// Query for the class definition, retrieving the class Body
ApexClass cls = [select Id,Name,Body from ApexClass where Name = 'MyApexClass' limit 1];
String body = String.valueOf(cls.Body);
String classDef = body.substring(0,body.indexOf('{'));
String classExtended;
if (classDef.contains('extends')){
    Integer extendsInitial = classDef.indexOf(' extends ');
    Integer extendsStarts = extendsInitial+9;
    Integer extendsEnds = classDef.indexOf(' ',extendsStarts);
    classExtended = body.substring(extendsStarts,extendsEnds);
    System.debug('Class ' + cls.Name + ' extends: ' + classExtended);
} else {
    System.debug('Class ' + cls.Name + ' does not extend another class');
}
```

You can then compare `classExtended` to whatever class you are wondering whether the class extends.

**(Scenario 2) Use System.Type and try/catch to determine whether a given type is an instance of another type**

```
String classToCheck = 'MyClassThatExtendsAnother';
String classExtended = 'MyBaseClass';

System.Type t = System.Type.forName(classToCheck);
MyBaseClass c;
try {
    c = (MyBaseClass) JSON.deserialize('{}',t);
} catch (Exception ex){}

if (c == null){
    System.debug('Class ' + classToCheck + ' does not extend ' + classExtended);
} else {
    System.debug('Class ' + classToCheck + ' DOES extend ' + classExtended);
}
```